# Dynamic method calling with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic-programming

For example I have class with two methods:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_one(value)

  end
  def method_two

  end
end
```

and method in controller where I call them:

```
  def example
    ex = Example.find(params[:id])
    ex.send(params[:method], params[:value]) if ex.respond_to?(params[:method])
  end
```

But the problem comes when I try to call `method_two`

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))
```

It happens because `params[:value]` returns `nil`. 
The easiest solution is:

```
  def example
    ex = Example.find(params[:id])
    if ex.respond_to?(params[:method])
      if params[:value].present?
        ex.send(params[:method], params[:value])
      else
        ex.send(params[:method])
      end
    end
  end
```

I wonder if there is any better workaround to do not pass argument if it's null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be really dangerous, so I recommend you filter the `params[:method]` before.

```
allowed_methods = {
  method_one: ->(ex){ex.method_one(params[:value])}
  method_two: ->(ex){ex.method_two}
}
allowed_methods[params[:method]]&.call(ex)
```

I defined an Hash mapping the methods name to a lambda calling the method, which handles arguments and any special case you want.

I only get a lambda if `params[:method]` is in the `allowed_methods` hash as a key.

The `&.` syntax is the new safe navigation operator in ruby 2.3, and - for short - executes the following method if the receiver is not nil (i.e. the result of `allowed_methods[params[:method]]`)
If you're not using ruby >= 2.3, you can use `try` instead, which have a similar behavior in this case :

```
allowed_methods[params[:method]].try(:call, ex)
```

If you don't filter the value of `params[:method]`, then a user can just pass `:destroy` for example to delete your entry, which is certainly not what you want.

Also, by calling `ex.send ...`, you bypass the object's encapsulation, which you usually shouldn't. To use only the public interface, prefer using `public_send`.

---

Another point on the big security flaw of you code:

`eval` is a private method defined on `Object` (actually inherited from `Kernel`), so you can use it this way on any object :

```
object = Object.new
object.send(:eval, '1+1') #=> 2
```

Now, with your code, imagine the user puts `eval` as the value of `params[:method]` and an arbitrary ruby code in `params[:value]`, he can actually do whatever he wants inside your application.

Comment: I was thinking there about security, but I didn't know the case with `eval`. Passing methods like `update`, `destroy` etc wasn't big deal for me, because it was one of the things I wanted to allow user to do.

I have one question. Why don't you `freeze` hash with allowed_methods ?

Comment: I recommend using something similar to what I first wrote in my answer, it will be more secure and handles per method the number of parameters.

Comment: `allowed_methods` is definitely a good idea, but the implementation is a perfect example of over-over-design. `%i|method_one method_two|` is enough. The trick with using carrying to the same amount of params is a very bad idea: it breaks SRP principle and basically makes this code unsupportable.

Comment: Then maybe add a `remote_method_call` on the object which does the job ? But it won't have access to singular params, so we have to pass the whole `params` which also breaks SRP... The best solution is to have different actions for different methods I think

Answer (score 1):

If you understand what you are doing, there are easier workarounds:

```
def method_two _ = nil
end
```

or

```
def method_two *
end
```

It works as well the other way round:

```
def method_one *args
end
def method_two *
end
```

and:

```
ex.public_send(params[:method], *[params[:value]]) \
  if ex.respond_to?(params[:method])
```

*Sidenote*: prefer `public_send` over `send` unless you are explicitly calling `private` method.

---

Using splatted params without modifying the methods signatures:

```
ex.public_send(*[params[:method], params[:value]].compact)
```

Comment: I would like to avoid modifying methods. Can you explain what does both of additions?

Comment: All the snippets above, save for the very first one, use [splatted params](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/). If you want to call different methods with different explicit signatures, you must perform a check or go with tricky `ex.public_send(*[params[:method], params[:value]].compact)`. The latter will remove the `nil` param in-place.